# How to merge array of objects with unique value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, unique

I have two array

```
[
 { date: '2020-05', visits: 0 },
 { date: '2020-04', visits: 0 },
 { date: '2020-03', visits: 0 },
   ....
   ....
 { date: '2019-07', visits: 0 },
 { date: '2019-06', visits: 0 }
]
```

and

```
[
 { date: '2019-08', visits: 47 },
 { date: '2019-09', visits: 120 },
 { date: '2019-10', visits: 69 },
 { date: '2019-12', visits: 1 },
 { date: '2020-01', visits: 378 },
 { date: '2020-02', visits: 355 }
]
```

I need into merge these arrays with unique dates?
Merge the first two arrays to get unique visits for a date
Need to fill the missing dates with visits '0'.

Expected result is

```
[
 { date: '2020-05', visits: 0 },
 { date: '2020-04', visits: 0 },
 { date: '2020-03', visits: 0 },
 { date: '2020-02', visits: 355 }
 { date: '2020-01', visits: 378 },
 { date: '2019-12', visits: 1 },
 { date: '2019-11', visits: 0 },
 { date: '2019-10', visits: 69 },
 { date: '2019-09', visits: 120 },
 { date: '2019-08', visits: 47 },
 { date: '2019-07', visits: 0 },
 { date: '2019-06', visits: 0 }
]
```

Comment: where is your specific problem with the task?

Comment: I need to merge the first two arrays to get unique visits for a date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a sort of hash map keyed by a date, and then converting this map to your desired data structure:

```js
const arr1 = [
 { date: '2019-08', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2019-09', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2019-10', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2019-12', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2020-01', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2020-02', visits: 5 }
];

const arr2 = [
 { date: '2019-08', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2019-09', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2019-10', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2019-12', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2020-01', visits: 5 },
 { date: '2020-05', visits: 5 }
];

const map = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!acc[cur.date]) {
    acc[cur.date] = cur.visits;
  } else {
    acc[cur.date] += cur.visits;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const results = Object.entries(map).map(([key, value]) => ({ date: key, visits: value }));
// even cleaner: const results = Object.entries(map).map(([date, visits]) => ({ date, visits }));
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

[...arr1, ...arr2] to merge arrays, if you have all dates (even with zero visits, that should be all.

If you don’t have all the dates, I would maks a map of dates in array converting to Date type and would find min and max dates, then just make a loop with adding 24h and convert Date back to string, and add missing date to array with value 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
const moment = require('moment');

let a  = [
    { date: '2020-05', visits: 0 },
    { date: '2020-04', visits: 0 },
    { date: '2020-03', visits: 0 },
    { date: '2019-07', visits: 0 },
    { date: '2019-06', visits: 0 },
    { date: '2019-08', visits: 3 }
];

let b = [
    { date: '2019-08', visits: 47 },
    { date: '2019-09', visits: 120 },
    { date: '2019-10', visits: 69 },
    { date: '2019-12', visits: 1 },
    { date: '2020-01', visits: 378 },
    { date: '2020-02', visits: 355 }
];

const merge = (a, b) => {
    [a, b] = a.length > b.length ? [[...a], [...b]] : [[...b], [...a]];
    a.forEach((x) => {
        let index = b.findIndex(y => (moment(y.date).isSame(moment(x.date))));
        if (index > -1) {
            b[index].visits += x.visits;
        } else {
            b.push(x);
        }
    });
    return b;
};

let c = merge(a, b);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c)
```